Not many discussions created by high-rep users
I took a look at the discussions feature of SO, and it seems like almost all of the new discussions are created by users of less than 100 reputation points. Is this actually true? Do more experienced users prefer to not use discussions? I did see, however, that high-rep users reply to a lot of discussions. Is there a reason for this?

One of the biggest uses for discussions I've seen is low rep users abusing discussions as a place to post their blatantly low quality questions. Without downvotes or a discussion ban system (yet), discussions seems like a more appealing location to ask then the regular Q/A.

The majority of users on the site are 100- rep (94.540 % or 80.332 % if you only consider users with visible posts) you'd expect the vast majority of all content on the site to be by users with 100 or less rep. People who answer questions tend to have higher reputation than those who ask. Providing good questions is much harder of a task. Given this is how the normal Q&A functions I'm not quite sure why it working the same way in Discussions is unexpected.

I will never use discussions since in my experience they are not used by any user with a positive contribution history. So I would absolutely disagree users with only 100 reputation use Discussions, in my experience, legitimate users rarely use it.

@Fastnlight I really like your choice of terminology there. One of the biggest uses. You didn't do the meta thing and call it a problem. Which is on point because at this juncture we can't be sure that this is not actually the intended purpose of discussions. A place where we have no power to obsessively rulebook people away.

They again made the mistake to boot a new place straight into Eternal September mode (that is, without seeding it with high-quality content, so the Eternal September state could at least be postponed). Reddit works much, much better and is a lot more interesting than Stack Overflow Forums.

cont ' - Some parts of Reddit are completely overrun by low-quality and uninteresting content, but many parts aren't. Some parts even contain useful content (interesting content is not necessarily useful)

There are a fair number of medium and high rep users posting in PHP discussions, but definitely almost all of the discussion starters are low-rep users. There's a lot of people just posting junk and AI responses as well.

i completely gave up on flagging discussions, and as such haven't really bothered reading them since. I felt like i was just spinning my wheels, so much of it is redundant or pointless and yet being served up to search engines at the same level as questions and answers. it's trash.

@KevinB, I feel the same way...almost all of it is just garbage

DiScUsSiOnS? What is that?  Oh yeah, another of those solutions the company shopped around for a problem to find.

@KevinB same here. In the beginning, I clicked on every discussion, sometimes gave responses with hints to the OP to better post a question, and flagged a lot. On some days 100% of the posts, (divided into spam, not a discussion, drawing attention to own questions, and troll posts). Signal-to-noise ratio1:20 at best, probably worse. But now I gave up, just occasionally flag spam when I see it.

"Is this actually true?" Statistically speaking there might be large uncertainties with the given comparably low number of discussions created. However, I think it's true. High rep users also rarely ask questions. They already know all the answers. So why should they start discussions.

"Do more experienced users prefer to not use discussions?" Yes.

If there were engaging and useful discussions, sure. But as said - because they crammed it into Stack Overflow, it has become more of a dumping site for "not Q&A stuff". Looking at discussions is just as tiring as looking at a feed of new questions.

Discussions also isn't well integrated into the rest of the site, hardly discoverable, and guidance or quality control is missing. Apart from that, even if high rep users don't create discussions there, it might be useful for some people.

Given the state of discussions and no signs of improvement or interest in improvement, it feels like eventually they'll just be removed and thus a waste of time to engage in

Can someone link to this "discussions feature of SO"?

@MathiasR.Jessen https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions

Wait, Discussions still exist?

@user3840170 As of June 28, 2024, yes, Discussions (Labs) still exists.

There are a lot of possible contributing factors. Off the top of my head:

There are just not as many high-rep users, and so they don't post as much in total; and when they do post, they're more likely to post answers than questions. After all, people who engage with the site over a long period are more likely to be more experienced people who can answer questions. Of the approximately 24 million non-deleted questions on the site, about 15 million belong to people with at least 100 reputation - but that's not accounting for reputation gained after asking the question, and the site was at its most active something like ten years ago. If we look at only the last week's data, only 30% or so of questions come from users with at least 100 reputation. (And let's be honest here; 100 is not a lot.)

If you're talking about the really high-rep users, generally they got that way by answering questions, and otherwise responding to the reputation incentives created by the site. Discussions don't grant reputation, and represent time not spent on things that would grant reputation. Little wonder that people highly motivated by reputation are not interested.

Another kind of high-rep user is the kind that spends a lot of time on Meta. Discussions aren't popular with this crowd - for many, it represents yet another way the site has lost its way.

Discussions are framed as a place that accept content that the rest of the site wouldn't. Low-rep users are generally new users and they're constantly complaining that the site isn't what they'd like it to be. Their questions get closed and downvoted for not meeting the site's standards and not being aligned with the site's goals. Little wonder they would be interested in participating in something other than asking questions normally.



I've a few replies in discussions but haven't started any because I don't have anything to discuss. Or at least not anything that belongs in Discussions.

In my experience it's also because for long-term users (not necessarily high-rep) it's harder to switch to the discussions mind-set.

Mine would be: I play by the rules. I don't understand why discussions exist on Stack Overflow, so don't know what is right or wrong to do. Hence I default to posting nothing at all.

@Cuzy by "normally" I meant that the Q&A is the part of the site where the questions are expected to be questions a priori, whereas a discussion is, well, seeking to discuss something.

@GertArnold, disscussions are plagiarised forums from e.g. GitHub or reddit. There they are mandatory instrument, here it's just another option to .. talk. If I have a question, I'd ask a question on StackOverflow. It's winning form of Q&A, why man need something else I yet to understand.

Less incentive (rep) to provide high quality content -> less high quality content.
If I have a choice, why would I go there?

@ChrisB "If I have a choice, why would I go there?" You might be bored, maybe? (Probably you aren't, just as a general comment.)
